# sound working fine butI get snd-hda-int error

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

when ever I try to update,Upgrade or remove old  package by running autoremove command I get the following error message.
I tried to use the following command same issue:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
---------------------------------------
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timerlibkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for seshagiri: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
seshagiri@seshagiri-Inspiron-3646:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic (5.4.0-81.91) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic (5.4.0-81.91) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-81-generic
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
```

---

Output of the command:
grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=1

I have followed the steps.I will get back to you and let you know if the issue is resolved. thank you.

Comment: `grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` please add this to your question

Comment: change in /etc/modpobe.d/alsa-base.conf `snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=1`to `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=1` or make an it to `# snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=1` so it will be ignored.